# Kinetic theory of photon gasses

Tags: photons, kinetic-theory

I have recently attempted to derive a fully functional non-handwavy derivation of the photon gas energy density without having to interpret some mass term such as $mc^2$ as the "photon energy".

My derivation has come to the point where I am left with this sum:

$P = \frac{1}{V} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N p_{x,i} v_{x,i}$

Here the indices simply refer to components, p is momentum, and v is velocity. We are summing over N photons in a volume. If I could prove that:

$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^N p_{x,i} v_{x,i} = \frac{E}{3}$

Then this derivation would be complete, but I cannot make any such conceptual leap. One option I had was to consider the "x-component" of energy, such that:

$p_{x,i} v_{x,i} = E_{x,i}$

Then by arguments of isotropic radiation inside a blackbox:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N E_{x,i} = \frac{E}{3} $

But I cannot make these assumptions based on anything. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit lost in your problems with $mc^2$, but in the special relativity for a massless particle your identity can be proved as follows.  First observation is
$$
v_x = |v| \frac{p_x}{|p|} = c \frac{p_x}{|p|},
$$
as far as for a photon the speed is always speed of light, $|v|=c$.  Then
$$
\sum p_xv_x = \frac{c}{|p|} \sum p_x^2.
$$
Then one can observe that due to symmetry the sum would be the same for any direction
$$
\sum p_x^2 = \sum p_y^2 = \sum p_y^2 = \frac{1}{3} \sum p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2
=\frac{1}{3}\sum p_i^2
$$
Thus
$$
\sum p_xv_x = \frac{1}{3} \sum \frac{c}{|p_i|} p_i^2 = \frac{1}{3}\sum cp_i = \frac{1}{3}\sum E_i = \frac{1}{3} E.
$$
Here of course you need to use special relativity, i.e. the relation $E_i=cp_i$ for a massless particle.  It follows from the generic relation $E^2 = c^4m^2+c^2p^2$ for a relativistic particle of any mass.

Comment: Just brilliant, thank you! This is precisely what I was looking for, I initially tried to find some relations through dot products of velocity and momentum, but I had totally forgot about using unit vectors! And my "problem" is that I don't want to include any effective mass terms, such as assuming that a photon acts as if it has mass such that $m = \frac{E}{c^2}$.